# Applying for a Schengen in Dubai as a tourist

Tags: schengen, dubai, tourist-visas, pakistani-citizens, uae

I'm on a residence visa in Dubai while my wife is on a long-term visit visa for now. We've saved up for our honeymoon and want to take a trip to somewhere in Europe. But is there any way she can apply for a visa to Spain (or Germany, France or anywhere really) while on a tourist visa here? Or does she have to apply in the home country (Pakistan). The problem with the latter is that it takes much longer to do than getting it done in Dubai. We have bank statements, and can get itineraries, tickets etc.

If not, does anyone know if she can get a visa to say Turkey or the UK or anywhere else while applying from the UAE on a tourist/visit visa?

Comment: @pnuts OP should then specify what that visa is, exactly